# Return type deduction for in-class friend functions

Tags: c++, auto, c++14, return-type-deduction

Here is a little experiment with [**return type deduction**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html) for in-class friend functions (using Clang 3.4 SVN and g++ 4.8.1 with `std=c++1y` in both cases) that is not documented in the linked working paper

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int a_;
    friend auto operator==(A const& L, A const& R) 
    { 
        return L.a_ == R.a_; // a_ is of type int, so should return bool
    }
};

template<class T>
struct B
{
    int b_;
    friend auto operator==(B const& L, B const& R) 
    { 
        return L.b_ == R.b_; // b_ is of type int, so should return bool
    }
};

using BI = B<int>;

int main()
{
    std::cout << (A{1} == A{2}) << "\n";    // OK for Clang, ERROR for g++
    std::cout << (BI{1} == BI{2}) << "\n";  // ERROR for both Clang and g++
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d5a7bcd7a6ee3c1).

**Question**: is automatic return type deduction for in-class friend functions supported in C++14?

Comment: I don't think the problem is specifically about *friend functions* defined inside templates. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9f8824e74a22d9a8) There is "Return type deduction for a function template with a placeholder in its declared type occurs when the
definition is instantiated even if the function body contains a return statement with a non-type-dependent operand" but I can't find anything about members of class templates or friend functions defined inside class templates.

Comment: As there's [temp.friend]/4 "When a function is defined in a friend function declaration in a class template, the function is instantiated
when the function is odr-used.", maybe the wording in [dcl.spec.auto]/12 should be "Return type deduction for a function template, member function of a class template and friend function defined inside a class template".

Comment: @DyP tnx for these quotes. The working paper I linked to above is not yet reflected in the current draft Standard, but I find the paper rather messy to read and there is no example that resembles the above code.

Comment: [The committee's draft github repository](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft) already incorporates that document.

Comment: Your example is misleading, the errors are where the functions are defined, not where you try to call them. You can comment out both lines in `main()` and it still fails (clang trunk even crashes on `operator==(const B&, const B&)`.)

Comment: @JonathanWakely clang++ 3.4 (trunk 184460) builds the example if the second comparison in `main` is commented out. This might be traced back to the fact that the friend functions defined in class templates are only instantiated when odr-used (and, as far as I can see, the point of instantiation is not defined in the Standard).

Comment: @JonathanWakely anything misleading was unintentional as i am simply trying to learn this new feature. at the point where i define the functions, the compiler seemingly has enough information to deduce bool as the return type, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: @DyP, right, but when instantiated the error is at the point of definition. TemplateRex, yes, I agree, I don't know if it's a bug in the implementations or a "feature"

Comment: "misleading" was a bit strong, sorry - I just meant that the error messages point to the definitions, not where your comments indicate (which I was surprised at when I compiled the code)

Comment: @JonathanWakely i sure hope the final C++14 standard will allow return type deduction in a fairly intuitive and *uniform* way without an unduly large number of exceptions (ideally limited to contexts where the type simply cannot yet be deduced)

Comment: Completely unrelated: Why is there a C++11 and especially, why is there a *trailing-return-type* tag?

Comment: @DyP C++11 because i wasn't sure which kind of deductions were already possible, and trailing-return type because return-type-deduction is not a tag yet and this seemed closest. Feel free to edit.

Comment: I'm always reluctant to edit tags, even more so if users with more rep than me set them ;) but in C++11, the only return type deduction possible is for lambdas, and trailing-return-type .. (well I wanted to write something but you already changed it ;)

Comment: @DyP if you could summarize your comments into an answer, I'd upvote and accept.

Comment: I'm not sure if what I extracted from the draft is sufficient to decide whether or not what you've done is legal (or whether or not it's a compiler bug). Even more, I'm interested if it's really underspecified like I suspect it to be.

Comment: There's been a related [bug in clang](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=16875), the version in stack-crooked's coliru doesn't have the fix yet. Also, see [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/d/topic/std-discussion/jahm7_tIN1Q/discussion).

Comment: @DyP omg, I got another really nasty version of this bug with a non-friend member `operator++(int)` inside a self-defined iterator class template, that was called with `*it++` in some algorithm. Error message: "error: indirection requires pointer operand ('auto' invalid)". Without this Q&A I would have never guessed the cause! I guess return type deduction is not ready for prime time yet.

Comment: off topic: oh my, I see a big problem in the draft : `Of course, using such a function in an expression when only a forward declaration has been seen is ill-formed`. This is terrible because it introduces dependencies like we never had with static return type functions. Also `int  f(); // error, declares a different function` this seems very disabling for people who code with templates and hierarchy of classes. Maybe people will want static overrides to statically assert code correction. This proposal is wicked IMO.

Comment: @DyP Care to add an answer now anyway? I don't think there will be much new insights now.

Comment: Maybe you'll get some attention now ;) In the meantime, things got.. better? In clang++3.4 trunk 192325 (recent) Debug build, an assertion fails for the line `L.b_ == R.b_`: *Assertion `AT->isDeduced() && "should have deduced to dependent type"` failed.*

Comment: I have *finally* tried it with a recent version of g++4.9.0 20131015 (from git commit fdbb424ac). The error message is quite interesting: *error: non-static data member declared `auto`*. This is of course nonsense, a (friend) function is not a data member. It works for both non-static and static member functions, though. You could file a bug report.

Comment: @DyP I might, but I don't wanna go through the trouble of compiling gcc myself, I tend to stick to Clang's nightly build Ubuntu packages. Thanks for checking though!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With respect to the other answers: We're dealing explicitly with [n3638](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html) here, and how it's incorporated in the recent drafts of C++1y.

I'm using 9514cc28 from the [commitee's github repository](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft), which incorporates some (minor) fixes/changes to n3638 already.

n3638 allows explicitly:

```
struct A {
  auto f(); // forward declaration
};
auto A::f() { return 42; }
```

And, as we can infer from [dcl.spec.auto], where this feature is specified, even the following will be legal:

```
struct A {
  auto f(); // forward declaration
};

A x;

auto A::f() { return 42; }

int main() { x.f(); }
```

(but more on this later)

This is fundamentally different from any *trailing-return-type* or dependent name lookup, as `auto f();` is a preliminary declaration, similar to `struct A;`. It needs to be completed later on, before it is used (before the return type is required).

Additionally, the problems in the OP are related to internal compiler errors. The recent clang++3.4 trunk 192325 Debug+Asserts build fails to compile as an assertion fails while parsing the line `return L.b_ == R.b_;`. I have not checked with a recent version of g++ as of now.

---

Is the OP's example legal wrt to a n3638?

This is a bit tricky IMO. (I'm always referring to 9514cc28 in this section.)

#### 1. Where is it allowed to use `auto`?

[dcl.spec.auto]

> 6    A program that uses `auto` or `decltype(auto)` in a context not explicitly allowed in this section is ill-formed.
>
> 2    The placeholder type can appear with a function declarator in the *decl-specifier-seq*, *type-specifier-seq*, *conversion-function-id*, or *trailing-return-type*, in any context where such a declarator is valid.

/5 also defines some contexts, but they're irrelevant here.

Therefore, `auto func()` and `auto operator@(..)` are generally allowed (this follows from the composition of a function declaration as `T D`, where `T` is of the form *decl-specifier-seq*, and `auto` is a *type-specifier*).

---

#### 2. Is it allowed to write `auto func();`, i.e. a declaration that is not a definition?

[dcl.spec.auto]/1 says

> The `auto` and `decltype(auto)` *type-specifiers* designate a placeholder type that will be replaced later, either by deduction from an initializer or by explicit specification with a *trailing-return-type*.

and /2

> If the declared return type of the function contains a placeholder type, the return type of the function is deduced from `return` statements in the body of the function, if any.

Although it doesn't *explicitly* allow a declaration like `auto f();` for a function (that is, a declaration without definition), it is clear from n3638 and [dcl.spec.auto]/11 that it is intended to be allowed, and not explicitly forbidden.

---

#### 3. What about friend functions?

So far, the example

```
struct A
{
    int a_;
    friend auto operator==(A const& L, A const& R);
}

auto operator==(A const& L, A const& R)
{ return L.a_ == R.a_; }
```

should be well-formed. The interesting part now is the definition of the friend function inside the definition of `A`, that is

```
struct A
{
    int a_;
    friend auto operator==(A const& L, A const& R)
    { return L.a_ == R.a_; } // allowed?
}
```

In my opinion, it is allowed. To support this, I'll cite name lookup. The name lookup inside the definition of functions defined in a friend function declaration follows the name lookup of member functions as per [basic.lookup.unqual]/9. /8 of the same section specifies unqualified lookup for names used inside member function bodies. One of the ways a name can be declared to be used is that it "shall be a member of class `X` or be a member of a base class of `X` (10.2)". This allows the widely known

```
struct X
{
    void foo() { m = 42; }
    int m;
};
```

Note how `m` isn't declared before its use in `foo`, but it's a member of `X`.

From this, I conclude that even

```
struct X
{
    auto foo() { return m; }
    int m;
}
```

is allowed. This is supported by clang++3.4 trunk 192325.
Name lookup requires to interpret this function only after the `struct` has been completed, also consider:

```
struct X
{
    auto foo() { return X(); }
    X() = delete;
};
```

Similarly, the body of friend functions defined inside a class can only be interpreted once the class is complete.

---

#### 4. What about templates?

Specifically, what about `friend auto some_function(B const& L) { return L.b_; }`?

First, the *injected-class-name* `B` is equivalent to `B<T>`, see [temp.local]/1. It refers to the *current instantiation* ([temp.dep.type]/1).

The *id-expression* `L.b_` refers to a *member of the current instantiation* (/4). It is also a *dependent member of the current instantiation* -- this is an addition made after C++11, see [DR1471](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1471), and I don't know what to think about it: [temp.dep.expr]/5 states this *id-expression* is *not* type-dependent, and as far as I see [temp.dep.constexpr] doesn't say it's value-dependent.

If the name in `L.b_` was not dependent, name lookup would follow the "usual name lookup" rules per [temp.nondep]. Else, this'll be fun (dependent name lookup is not very well specified), but considering that

```
template<class T>
struct A
{
    int foo() { return m; }
    int m;
};
```

is accepted by most compilers as well, I think the version with `auto` should be valid, too.

There's also a section about friends of templates in [temp.friend], but IMO it doesn't shed light on the name lookup here.

---

Also see [this highly relevant discussion in the isocpp-forum](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/jahm7_tIN1Q/discussion).

Comment: +10 if I could, but great stuff that I need to process. Thanks a lot!

Comment: IIRC, friend functions defined inside class templates are regular functions in the enclosing namespace, and can only be found through ADL. Since you mention some technicalities related to instantiation, I wonder if there is interference from 2-phase name lookup here. Specifically, exactly *when* is the return type deduced?

Comment: @TemplateRex [class.friend]/7 "A `friend` function defined in a class is in the (lexical) scope of the class in which it is defined." - this impacts unqualified lookup (plus it is implicitly `inline`). "Specifically, exactly when is the return type deduced?" Good question; I've already said in the comments to your question that I cannot find an explicit statement for this. However, as also appears in the linked isocpp discussion, it can't be before the enclosing class is completed.

Comment: OK, I guess there both the Standard and current QoI to consider, perhaps it'll get clear in the coming months. I'll accept the answer at the end of the weekend in the remote event that something better comes along.