# Return type deduction for class methods? C++1y

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14, return-type-deduction

Is return type deduction allowed for member functions in c++14, or only for free functions?

I ask because I sort of implicitly assumed it would work, but in gcc 4.8.1 I get an internal compiler error("in gen_type_die_with_usage"). First time I have ever gotten such a cryptic error like that, so I am a bit skeptical; and I know they have changed the spec since then.

For clarity this works for me:

```
auto foo() {return 5;}
```

but this doesn't:

```
class Bar{
auto baz() {return 5;}
}
```

Is this allowed in the draft standard?

Comment: Return type deduction is only supported as of gcc 4.9.

Comment: @bamboon the support table on the gcc site cites another standard proposal on that row for version 4.8. Is the current version so much different?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think so. Your code works fine with my version of gcc 4.9. See the link I posted in the comment of aaronman's answer.

Comment: @bamboon Ok, well you answered what I wanted to know but didn't ask: if it works in a newer version.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18931993/420683

Comment: An internal compiler error is *always* a bug in the compiler, it does not mean "your code is invalid".  Your code still might be invalid, but don't interpret an ICE to mean that!

Comment: @JonathanWakely Well that's why I asked the question. I have never gotten an internal compiler error, so I had no idea how to interpret it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the standard should allow it according to the paper [n3582](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3582.html). Here is an example from the paper.

> Allowing non-defining function declarations with auto return type is not strictly    necessary, but it is useful for coding styles that prefer to define member functions outside the class:

```
    struct A {
      auto f(); // forward declaration
    };
    auto A::f() { return 42; }
```

> and if we allow it in that situation, it should be valid in other situations as well. Allowing it is also the more orthogonal choice; in general, I believe that if combining two features can work, it should work.

According to the comment by @bamboon, "Return type deduction is only supported as of gcc 4.9." so that would explain why you don't have it.

Comment: Yeah, the changelog at least says that the implementation now conforms to N3638. http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.9/changes.html

Comment: [This page](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx1y.html) gave me the sense it should work. But no matter... It is good to know I didn't misunderstand the standard. I will just install 4.9