# CRTP and c++1y return type deduction

Tags: c++, c++11, crtp, c++14, return-type-deduction

I was recently playing with CRTP when I came across something that surprised me when used with c++1y functions whose type is deduced. The following code works:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct Base
{
    auto foo()
    {
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo_impl();
    }
};

struct Derived:
    public Base<Derived>
{
    auto foo_impl()
        -> int
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Derived b;
    int i = b.foo();
    (void)i;
}
```

I assumed that the return type from `Base<Derived>::foo` was a `decltype` of the expression returned, but if I modify the functio `foo` like this:

```
auto foo()
    -> decltype(static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo_impl())
{
    return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo_impl();
}
```

This code does not work anymore, I get the following error (from GCC 4.8.1):

```
||In instantiation of 'struct Base<Derived>':|
|required from here|
|error: invalid static_cast from type 'Base<Derived>* const' to type 'Derived*'|
||In function 'int main()':|
|error: 'struct Derived' has no member named 'foo'|
```

My questions are: Why doesn't it work? What could I possibly write to get the correct return type without relying on automatic return type deduction?

And, well... here is a [live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4c39f214bf59436).

Comment: Without reading everything, if you are using gcc 4.8, this might be interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846097/return-type-deduction-for-class-methods-c1y?noredirect=1#comment29514740_19846097.

Comment: @bamboon Good point. It would be good to know whether my example is valid behaviour then^^"

Comment: I think there is a chance that this is impossible to do without c++14 auto, Derived has no `foo_impl` at the  time of the trailing return type

Comment: _"I assumed that the return type from `Base<Derived>::foo` was a `decltype` of the expression returned"_: actually `auto` return type deduction is closer to a "[_decayed_](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) decltype" (e.g. it strips reference, top-level const...). Now for your problem, maybe it's that when "instantiating" `foo`'s "signature" (in instantiation of `Base<Derived>` requested from the definition of `Derived`) `Derived` has not been completely defined yet so you can't downcast here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Why does the first example work (return type deduction)?

The definition of a member function of a class template is only implicitly instantiated when odr-used (or explicitly instantiated). That is, by deriving from `Base<Derived>`, you do *not* implicitly instantiate the function body. Hence, the return type is still *not deduced yet*.

At the (*) point of instantiation, `Derived` is complete, `Derived::foo_impl` is declared, and the return type deduction can succeed.

<sub>(*) not "the", but "certain points of instantiation". There are several.</sub>

---

#### Why doesn't the second example work (trailing-return-type)?

> I assumed that the return type from `Base<Derived>::foo` was a `decltype`
>   of the expression returned, but if I modify the function `foo` like this:

The *trailing-return-type* is part of the declaration of the member function; hence, it is part of the definition of the surrounding class, which is required to be instantiated when deriving from `Base<Derived>`. At this point, `Derived` is still incomplete, specifically `Derived::foo_impl` has not been declared yet.

---

> What could I possibly write to get the correct return type without
>   relying on automatic return type deduction?

Now this is tricky. I'd say this is not very clearly defined in the Standard, e.g. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17478621/420683).

Here's an example that demonstrates that clang++3.4 does not find the members of `Derived` inside `Base<Derived>`:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct Base
{
    auto foo() -> decltype( std::declval<Derived&>().foo_impl() )
    {
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo_impl();
    }
};
```

`declval` doesn't require a complete type, so the error message is that there's no `foo_impl` in `Derived`.

---

There's a hack, but I'm not sure if it's compliant:

```
template<typename Derived>
struct Base
{
    template<class C = Derived>
    auto foo() -> decltype( static_cast<C*>(this)->foo_impl() )
    {
        static_assert(std::is_same<C, Derived>{}, "you broke my hack :(");
        return static_cast<Derived*>(this)->foo_impl();
    }
};
```

Comment: But can you actually make it compile using only c++11

Comment: @aaronman That is a question of name lookup; i.e. can the names of the class `Derived` be accessed inside the class template specialization `Base<Derived>` *at the point when `Base<Derived>` is instantiated*. I think it is not completely clear from the Standard (dependent name lookup), but I'd say it's rather *not* allowed to access those names (they're not found).

Comment: Right I think it might actually be impossible

Comment: To make the workaround more 'resilient' you can do something like `template<typename Dependent = void>` and then use `typename constant<Derived, Dependent>::type` to mean `Derived`, where `template<typename C, typename... Ignored> struct constant { using type = C; };` -- then it doesn't matter what `foo` is instantiated with. (Machiavellian code can introduce a specialization of `constant` for hijacks and hijinks though.)

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered a solution, perhaps not very pretty, but I think it's pretty standard compliant.

***It's been pointed out that this is quite limited as it assumes that `foo_impl` can be implemented without accessing other parts of Derived or Base.  Thanks @DyP. I've updated this answer with another approach.***

Anyway, in terms of answering why the original code doesn't work, I defer to everyone else and to @Dyp's answer.  I learned a lot, well described.

The basic issue, in layman's terms, (in my limited understanding!), is that when the compiler sees this line:

```
struct Derived:    public Base<Derived>
```

it immediately wants/needs to know some/all information about `Base<Derived>` even though it hasn't seen the following lines yet which define `foo_impl`.

<strike>A solution is to move `foo_impl` into another class called `NotQuiteDerived`.  Then `Derived` inherits from this as well as from `Base<...,...>`. This allows us to put `foo_impl` before the introduction of `Derived`.  Then we need a second template type parameter in `Base`.  Anyway, the code can speak for itself ! :</strike>

I've changed this to a simpler, and maybe slightly better approach.  `Base` doesn't need to see all of `Derived`, but the signature of `foo_impl`.  This can be passed along with the CRTP parameter.

---

Another approach now that is more flexible than the last, as it allows `foo_impl` to have more access to `Derived` and to act as if it was effectively a method of `Derived`.  We can declare `foo_impl` as a friend of `Derived` immediately before the `struct Derived: ...`.  This allows the implementation of `foo_impl` to see the full definition of everything, and it allows the `Base` to be given the return type of `foo_impl`.

```
template<typename Derived, typename TypeOfTheFriendFunction>
struct Base
{
    auto foo() -> typename std::function<TypeOfTheFriendFunction> :: result_type
    {
        return foo_impl_as_friend(static_cast<Derived*>(this) /*, any other args here*/);
    }
};

struct Derived;
auto foo_impl_as_friend(Derived * This /*, any other args here*/) -> std::string;

struct Derived:
    public Base<Derived, decltype(foo_impl_as_friend ) >
{
        private:
        void method_that_foo_impl_needs() { }   // Just to demonstrate that foo_impl can act as part of Derived

        friend decltype(foo_impl_as_friend) foo_impl_as_friend;
};

auto foo_impl_as_friend(Derived *This) -> std::string
{
        This -> method_that_foo_impl_needs();
        return "a string";
}
```

Comment: While it may work, it assumes that the return type of `foo_impl` is always `int` while it may change in function of the derived class :/

Comment: It doesn't make that assumption.  The word `int` only appears in one place, in `foo_impl`.  You're free to change that.  And you could replace `int` by a decltype based on the return statement inside `foo_impl`.

Comment: An interesting workaround, if you don't need `Base<..>` as a base class to define `foo_impl`.

Comment: @Dyp, good point.  That is a big limitation!  Perhaps `foo_impl` should be taken out and defined as a free (friend) function.  Then it would be passed through along with the CRTP parameter.  In this, `NotQuiteDerived` is just a way to pass information about `foo_impl` through to the Base.

Comment: I've extended my solution to make it have more access to `Derived`.

Comment: *"It's been pointed out that this is quite limited"* Well, typically, in the template pattern (which can be implemented as static polymorphism via CRTP), you wouldn't call base class functions anyway -- so it's *appropriate and useful* if you don't need to call base class functions from the derived class.

Comment: @Dyp, I would never have thought of that.  To be honest, I don't think I've every actually used the CRTP in real code, so I'm not the best judge of what's useful and what isn't!  Either way though, your method-template solution seems to do the trick very nicely.