# Why does auto return type deduction work with not fully defined types?

Tags: c++, c++14, crtp, return-type-deduction

Consider the following:

```
template<typename Der>
struct Base {
    // NOTE: if I replace the decltype(...) below with auto, code compiles
    decltype(&Der::operator()) getCallOperator() const {
        return &Der::operator();
    }
};

struct Foo : Base<Foo> {
    double operator()(int, int) const {
        return 0.0;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    auto callOp = f.getCallOperator();
}
```

I want to create a member function in CRTP base class with a return type depending on signature of the `operator()` in the derived class. However `decltype(&Der::operator())` fails to compile; The `operator()` member function in `Foo` is not visible. I assume that this is because the base class template is instantiated before `Foo` is fully defined.

Surprisingly, if I place `auto` for the return type it compiles. I assumed that `auto` would make the compiler deduce the return type from the function body and fail - because the body uses the not fully defined `Foo` type.

This behavior is the same for both MSVC 2015.3 and Clang 3.8

Why did the code start to work with `auto`? Does `auto` type deduction somehow "delay" the instantiation? Or use a different context than a hand-written return type expression?

Comment: Good question. Upvoted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CRTP and c++1y return type deduction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19892479/crtp-and-c1y-return-type-deduction)

Comment: Its the same issue but question and answer approach it from slightly different angle. Here we have "how the auto deduction is different", the linked question and its answer is more about "how can I make the hand-written expression work". Though it may still qualify as duplicate…

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your guess is correct. A deduced return type is not actually deduced until the signature of the function is needed. This means that it will be deduced in the context of the call to `getCallOperator`, at which point `Foo` is fully defined.

This is specified in 7.1.6.4p12:

> Return type deduction for a function template with a placeholder in its declared type occurs when the definition is instantiated even if the function body contains a return statement with a non-type-dependent operand.