# return type deduction and function declarations

Tags: c++, c++14, return-type-deduction

How can I declare a function in a class that uses return type deduction?

This is fine:

```
auto foo() {
    return 5;
}
```

But this does not work:

```
class Test {
    auto foo();
};
auto Test::foo() {
    return 5;
}
```

> internal compiler error: in gen_type_die_with_usage, at dwarf2out.c:19486

I don't know if it has anything to do with it but I am using QtCreator 3.3.

**EDIT**:
I am using Qt 5.4 and QtCreator 3.3.
I have added `CONFIG   += c++14` to the project file.
By default, I am using GCC 4.8.2 and I guess this is why I get the error (I need [4.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846097/return-type-deduction-for-class-methods-c1y)). However when I use Clang 3.5 ([3.4](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) is needed) it says

> error: 'auto' return without trailing return type; deduced return types are a C++1y extension

**EDIT2**: This seems to be a bug with Qt and not with GCC. Outside of Qt I can write class functions with return type deductions and it compiles and runs just fine with GCC 4.8.2 and Clang 3.5.0

Comment: I doubt that "Error 1" is all you get. Please post the *complete* error log.

Comment: [cannot reproduce](http://ideone.com/1fDjZH)

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: You are correct, Qt Creator did not classify the internal compiler error as an error, so I did not see it.

Comment: Please tell me how to improve my question instead of just downvoting me.

Comment: What compiler is QtCreator using? What version of the compiler? You do pass the correct flags so it compiles in C++14 mode? No matter what, you apparently found a compiler bug, so you should go to the compilers bug-page and report it (if it's not reported already).

Comment: on here:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php

using (GNU GCC v4.8.3), your code compiles and runs but generates warnings. If you set your settings to "treat warnings as errors" it would of course not compile

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: I edited my question. Is it really a compiler bug? [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846097/return-type-deduction-for-class-methods-c1y) it says that I need GCC 4.9. But I wonder why it doesn't work with Clang 3.5, maybe I still need to configure something in QtCreator?

Comment: Internal compiler error means that "the compiler hit something it didn't expect". This is a BUG, report it to the maker of the compiler you are using...

Comment: @CashCow: Ok, so it seems I don't need GCC 4.9 after all. Maybe it was added with 4.8.3 and is not in there in 4.8.2?

Comment: @Mats Petersson: Okay, I did.