# C++14 support in QtCreator with Clang

Tags: c++, clang, qt-creator, c++14

How can I enable C++14 support in QtCreator 3.3 using Clang 3.5? I have added a Clang kit and I have added `CONFIG   += c++14` in my project file. However when using e.g. [return type deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857253/return-type-deduction-and-function-declarations) I get the following error:

> error: 'auto' return without trailing return type; deduced return types are a C++1y extension

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27857253/862973

Comment: have you duplicated your own question?

Comment: The error message should give you a hint with the "C++1***y***" part. Try using e.g. `c++1y` instead. Possibly you need to add e.g. `-std=c++14` (or `-std=c++1y`) somewhere (I'm not that familiar with QtCreator and its configuration file).

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9878792/862973

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: [their status page](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) says _"You can use Clang in C++14 mode with the -std=c++14 option (use -std=c++1y in Clang 3.4 and earlier)."_ which I'd interpret as _"`-std=c++14` can be used with the same effect as `-std=c++1y` in 3.5 and above"_.

Comment: @Idgorman: My other question was about the error in GCC. Now I'm asking how to enable Clang so I can get around the error in GCC.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: I'm not familiar with the configuration files either. I tried adding c++14 but then both c++14 and c++11 was added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to go to the Makefile in the build folder and manually replace `-std=c++11` with `-std=c++14`.

Thankfully the Makefile is only written once when you add the kit to the project. I only had to do this once and could build in QtCreator as often as I want.

So now I can use a Clang kit to use all the new c++14 features. As a bonus, I can also use all the c++17 features if I manually set `-std=c++1z` in the Makefile. Sweet!

Comment: You could do `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++1z` in `.pro` file instead

Comment: @Drop: I tried that before. It doesn't work because somehow it adds `-std=c++1z` **and** `-std=c++11` to the Makefile.

Comment: Do you forget to remove `CONFIG   += c++14`?

Comment: @nib: I think when I removed it, it added -std=c++03 instead.

Comment: Ive tested now, `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++1y` works as expected for return type deduction. Also in Qt5.5 `CONFIG += c++14` is available. For previous versions of Qt you can even create your own `mkspecs/features/c++14.prf`.

Answer (score 6):

you can use `CONFIG += c++14` in `.pro` file with Qt5.5

but there is a bug with clang, so we need to modify the `Qt/5.5/clang_64/mkspecs/features/c++14.prf` file, 
add this code before`include(c++11.prf)` :

```
contains(QMAKE_LFLAGS_CXX11, -stdlib=libc++) {
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX11 += -stdlib=libc++
}
```

Comment: My `c++14.prf` file had guards which were meant to stop `-std=c++1y` being specified if Clang was earlier than 3.2. or version 4 on Apple. I commented out those guards - touch wood, it works!