# Qt does not use C++14 Standard Library

Tags: c++, qt, clang, c++14, libc++

Recently, by looking at the source code of `std::move`, I discovered that Qt links my programs with a version of the Standard Library which does not support C++11/14 features:

```
#ifndef _LIBCPP_HAS_NO_RVALUE_REFERENCES

template <class _Tp>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX11
typename remove_reference<_Tp>::type&&
move(_Tp&& __t) _NOEXCEPT
{
    typedef typename remove_reference<_Tp>::type _Up;
    return static_cast<_Up&&>(__t);
}

#else  // _LIBCPP_HAS_NO_RVALUE_REFERENCES

template <class _Tp>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
_Tp&
move(_Tp& __t)
{
    return __t;
}

template <class _Tp>
inline _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY
const _Tp&
move(const _Tp& __t)
{
    return __t;
}

#endif  // _LIBCPP_HAS_NO_RVALUE_REFERENCES
```

Actually, the macro `_LIBCPP_HAS_NO_RVALUE_REFERENCES` is defined (I use `CONFIG += C++14` in my `.pro` file, but this is a problem of the library).

Do I have to rebuild libc++ in order to use C++ features (like proper `std::move`) with Qt? Or maybe I have to change some settings?

I use Qt 5.7 with LLVM 7.3.0.

Comment: It isn't supported, take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26127217/6614294)

Comment: @JamesCalder I can use C++11/14 features, but I'm using a version of libc++ which does not support C++11/14.

Comment: You wrong. Started from Qt 5.7 compiler should support at least C++11. So they are using it. And they do a lot of refactoring to optimize performance with C++11 features like move ctors or perfect forwarding.

Comment: I doubt that it's using C++11 since _LIBCPP_HAS_NO_RVALUE_REFERENCES is defined

Comment: Which version of qt are you using?

Comment: Qt 5.7 with LLVM 7.3.0

Comment: Maybe same problem as this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27858273/c14-support-in-qtcreator-with-clang

Comment: Check where it's defined. It might be a problem with compiler detection. I presume that you've build Qt yourself? What was the `configure` line? You can find it in the build folder in `qtbase/config.status`.

Comment: It's defined in `type_traits` (as far as I know it should be defined in `utility`).
No, I have not build Qt by myself.

Comment: Qt does not ship with an implementation of the standard library. Any implementation it's trying to link against was already present. Also, Qt 5.7 *requires* at least C++11 (though not 14).

Answer (score 1):

Qt uses whatever standard library your [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) is using by default. This problem has nothing to do with Qt, anything you compile with your LLVM will suffer from the same issue. Most likely your LLVM install is borked.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this tons of times before. You're currently including libstdc++ v4.2 or something. You need to add -stdlib=libc++. Then C++14 will start to work.