# Template friend function and return type deduction

Tags: c++, templates, friend, c++14, return-type-deduction

Note: This question is really close to [Return type deduction for in-class friend functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931993/return-type-deduction-for-in-class-friend-functions), but I did not find the answer to my problem there.

Tested with clang 3.4 with std=c++1y and clang 3.5 with std=c++14 and std=c++1z

This code compiles:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass(T const& a) : impl(a) {}

        template<class T0, class T1> friend auto
        // requires operator+(T0,T1) exists
        operator+(MyClass<T0> const& a, MyClass<T1> const& b)
        {
            return MyClass<decltype(a.impl+b.impl)>{a.impl + b.impl};
        }

        T getImpl() const { return impl; }

    private:
        T impl;
};

int main() {
    MyClass<int> x(2);
    MyClass<long> y(2);

    auto z = x+y;
    std::cout << z.getImpl() << "\n";
}
```

Now if I define operator+ outside of the class, it does not compile anymore:

```
template<class T>
class MyClass {
    public:
        MyClass(T const& a) : impl(a) {}

        template<class T0, class T1> friend auto
        operator+(MyClass<T0> const& a, MyClass<T1> const& b);

        T getImpl() const { return impl; }
    private:
        T impl;
};

template<class T0, class T1> auto
operator+(MyClass<T0> const& a, MyClass<T1> const& b)
{
    return MyClass<decltype(a.impl+b.impl)>{a.impl + b.impl};
}
```

Clang 3.4 says:

```
error: use of overloaded operator '+' is ambiguous (with operand types MyClass<int> and MyClass<long>)
```

And then points at what it believes to be two different functions: the declaration in the class and the definition outside the class.

My question is: is it a clang bug, or just that template parameters are deduced for a friend function thus leading the two functions not being equivalent is some cases ?
And what alternative would you suggest: make operator+ a member function, or define friend operator+ inside the class (which would in my opinion clutter the class interface) ?

Just for your information, I have a real use case of such code, where I try to wrap a third -party matrix class and I need return type deduction because of the use of expression template for lazy evaluation.

*Edit*: The following does work (but still clutters the interface...)

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
    T impl;

public:
    explicit MyClass(T a) : impl(std::move(a)) { }

    T const& getImpl() const { return impl; }

    template<typename T0, typename T1>
    friend auto operator +(MyClass<T0> const& a, MyClass<T1> const& b) -> MyClass<decltype(a.impl + b.impl)>;
};

template<typename T0, typename T1>
auto operator +(MyClass<T0> const& a, MyClass<T1> const& b) -> MyClass<decltype(a.impl + b.impl)>
{
    return MyClass<decltype(a.impl + b.impl)>(a.impl + b.impl);
}
```

Comment: I haven't read C++14 yet, but is `auto` without a trailing return type actually allowed on non-defining function declarations?

Comment: I don't know what the standard says, but clang accepts it, at least for member functions. I think it is related to the fact that you cannot overload based on the return type.

Comment: The opposite happens when I tried VS 2015. The former fails with "error C2995: 'auto operator +(const MyClass<T> &,const MyClass<T1> &)': function template has already been defined" and the latter compiles and runs. It looks like VS duplicates the member if it is embedded, causing two definitions of `operator+<int,long>`.

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fef5c229e7a62bb) works, [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa2e4ef111f26c4f) doesn't – it's not apparent to me why there should be any difference between the two.

Comment: @ildjarn I will edit my question with that

Answer (score 1):

edit:
look at the comments section, it's a bug in gcc 4.8.2 and 4.9

Gcc error code:

> prog.cpp:10:61: error: non-static data member declared 'auto'
>            operator+(MyClass const& a, MyClass const& b)
>                                                                ^ prog.cpp: In function 'int main()': prog.cpp:25:15: error: no match
>   for 'operator+' (operand types are 'MyClass' and 'MyClass')
>        auto z = x+y;
>                  ^

Comment: Yes but what is the problem? operator+(MyClass<int>,MyClass<long>) and operator+(MyClass<long>,MyClass<int>) have different signatures. They can therefore return different values

Comment: Gcc message is also strange, because MyClass is not a type, but a template.

Comment: @dyp you answered very precisely the question I linked and seem to know the subject very well, do you have any clue for this one ?

Comment: @Bérenger It does look a lot like a bug. For example the behaviour is different ("normal") when not using return type deduction, or even when the class that befriends the function is not a template: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe1e67ac341b3216

Comment: @Bérenger an instantiation of a template class, is a type.

Comment: @dau_sama Yes but where is it instanciated? If you look at the question I mentionned, it is written in the answer that the compiler can implicitly instanciate MyClass as MyClass<T> (T being the template parameter defined in MyClass). But here I already provided parameters T0 and T1 (i.e. int and long). But gcc never mentions them...

Comment: @dyp nice spot, it is indeed a bug.